# Failed to load SKSpriteNode with UIImage texture into ARKit SCNNode

Tags: image, textures, arkit, skspritenode, scnnode

Failed to load SKSpriteNode with UIImage texture into ARKit SCNNode

I am trying to display a barcode image on a SCNNode reside in an AR WorldTracking session, unfortunately, I just can’t make it work and am hoping someone could help me to solve this problem. The following is a list of steps I took:

1. create a SpriteKit scene through SKScene editor
2. create a SpriteNode inside this SpriteKit scene (in SKScene editor), this node will hold a UIImage object created by a barcode generator method
3. switch to ViewController.swift, load this SKScene and retrieve SpriteNode created in step-2
4. update the texture of SpriteNode by an UIImage object returned by a barcode generator method (which returns UIImage)
5. create a SCNode and set this node’s Geometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents  to the SpriteKit scene created in step-1
6. add this SCNNode to sceneView.scene.rootNode

For debugging purpose, I’ve also created a UIImageView on main screen and load barcode image so I can tell if barcode image has been created

The result: barcode displayed on UIImageView properly but not on SCNNode. The source codes of ViewController.swift is listed as below . Can someone please review my codes and let me know why I can't get barcode displayed in AR session properly and how I can fix this program? Thank you very much.

```
import UIKit
import SceneKit
import ARKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, ARSCNViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var sceneView: ARSCNView!

    @IBOutlet weak var barcodeView: UIImageView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Set the view's delegate
        sceneView.delegate = self

        // Show statistics such as fps and timing information
        sceneView.showsStatistics = true

        // Create a new scene
        let scene = SCNScene()

        // Set the scene to the view
        sceneView.scene = scene

        loadBarcode()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        // Create a session configuration
        let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()

        // Run the view's session
        sceneView.session.run(configuration)
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

        // Pause the view's session
        sceneView.session.pause()
    }

    // MARK: - ARSCNViewDelegate

/*
    // Override to create and configure nodes for anchors added to the view's session.
    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SCNNode? {
        let node = SCNNode()

        return node
    }
*/

    func session(_ session: ARSession, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        // Present an error message to the user

    }

    func sessionWasInterrupted(_ session: ARSession) {
        // Inform the user that the session has been interrupted, for example, by presenting an overlay

    }

    func sessionInterruptionEnded(_ session: ARSession) {
        // Reset tracking and/or remove existing anchors if consistent tracking is required

    }

    func loadBarcode() {
        guard let barcodeScene = SKScene(fileNamed: "art.scnassets/barcodeSKScene.sks") else {
            fatalError("failed to load barcodeSKScene.sks from project")
        }
        guard let barcodeNode = barcodeScene.childNode(withName: "barcodeSKNode") as! SKSpriteNode? else {
            fatalError("failed to get barcode node from SKScene")
        }
        guard let barcodeImage = getBarcodeImage() else {
            fatalError("failed to get barcode")
        }
        barcodeNode.texture = SKTexture(image:barcodeImage )
        let planeGeometry = SCNPlane(width: 0.5, height: 0.3)
        planeGeometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = barcodeScene
        let planeNode = SCNNode(geometry: planeGeometry)
        planeNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: -2.0)
        sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(planeNode)
        barcodeView.image = barcodeImage
    }

    func getBarcodeImage() -> UIImage? {
        return generateBarcode(from: "A0123456789")
    }

    func generateBarcode(from string: String) -> UIImage? {
        let data = string.data(using: String.Encoding.ascii)

        if let filter = CIFilter(name: "CICode128BarcodeGenerator") {
            filter.setValue(data, forKey: "inputMessage")
            let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 3, y: 3)

            if let output = filter.outputImage?.transformed(by: transform) {
                return UIImage(ciImage: output)
            }
        }

        return nil
    }
}
```

I want to display SpriteNode (with a image as texture) in a SpriteKit scene on SCNNode (in ARKit)

Comment: Why don't you directly use the `UIImage` on your `SCNNode`? Is there a point using Sprite nodes to attach image?

Comment: I tried to apply UIImage to SCNNode but got the same problem

Comment: Also, the SpriteKit scene has other Label Nodes, I need the whole SpriteKid scene to display label nodes and spritenode all together